# Nodejs inject virtual machine

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine, code-injection

I need to inject code that runs in nodejs virtual machine (`vm` module). I have modified `require` function, but it returns only allowed modules. Code of `require` function:

```
function (name){
    return modules.indexOf(name) > -1 ? require(name) : {};
}
```

Probably, we can inject modules required by this function. So, can we inject a virtual machine that it can run code outside of it?

Allowed modules: [canvas](https://npmjs.com/package/canvas) and [https](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https)

Comment: So, you have JS you want to run in your VM, but the modules in that code are not working when executed?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin It's not mine ;d. I can just provide `require` in context. I need to inject code, not to require any module